# I'm having trouble finding the error in my String searching code in java?

Tags: java, loops, nested-loops

I'm working on my own version of String and one of its object methods should be able to take a normal string and search for it. The class is called MyString and has two member variables, the length of the string it contains and an array of the string. The full class is below with the method I'm having trouble on being the last one down.

The only time that the indexOf method doesn't work is when the string is contained at the end of the MyString array. I get a -1 returned instead of the index where it should be found.

Test cases:
Initialize MyString with "Trastamara" string. If I search for "mara", or "amara", or even "Trastamara" anything that ends with the last character of the string, it won't find the string.

```
public class MyString {
private int length;
private char[] characters;

public MyString()
{
    length = 0;
}

public MyString(String s)
{
    length = s.length();
    characters = new char[length];
    for(int i = 0; i <length; i++)
    {
        characters[i] = s.charAt(i);
    }

}

public int indexOf(String s)
{
    char[] sa = s.toCharArray();
    int lastIndex = length - s.length();
    int convoluted=0;
    for(int i=1; i<=lastIndex;i++)
    {
        if(convoluted==s.length())
        {
            return i-1;
        } else convoluted=0;
        for(int j=0, k=i; j<s.length(); j++, k++)
        {
            if(sa[j]==characters[k])
            {
                convoluted++;
            }
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: Why do you have a length field, since you already have an array of characters, and you can thus use the length of the array directly?

Comment: @GBlodgett It returns a -1 to indicate that the string wasn't found

Comment: Could you provide your test cases?

Comment: Also since this is only a problem with the one method, you might want to edit out all the other code so that others don't have to go searching to find the problematic code. (See [MCVE])

Comment: @GBlodgett I added a description of some test cases

Comment: What if you used `String.subString(int, int);`? (Likely won't help with the bug, just easier to program) Also, where is `k` initialized?

Comment: @FailingCoder I think the syntax for initializing k is correct isn't it? It's in the for loop description, right? Also, the point of this is to avoid using as many string methods as possible, so using `.substring()` isn't an option unfortunately

Comment: Oh oops, your syntax is correct. Why not use `String.substring(int)` though?

Comment: You're iterating one too few times. Change the loop to: `for(int i=1; i<=lastIndex+1;i++)`

Comment: @FailingCoder It's just a part of the assignment directions

Comment: @GBlodgett I see! But I would have to check to see if i was equal to lastIndex+1 before proceeding to the nested loop wouldn't I? Because if the very last character is not identical then the nested loop will attempt to generate an out of bounds index for the main `MyString` array, right?

Comment: @Elmer Correct.

Comment: @Elmer, btw, why do you create a new array `char[] sa`, instead of just using `s.charAt()` (since String implements CharSequence interface)?

Comment: @PavelSmirnov No reason other than that I'm trying to familiarize myself with arrays, but I definitely see how using `s.charAt()` would have been more straightforward